# Generate EXCEL, PDF, CSV report with limited file size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel, pdf

I am able to generate a report in my `PHP` application for `EXCEL`, `PDF` and `CSV` using `JQuery`. Sometimes, size of generated report size is 500 MB and more. I want **to limit this size of generating reports to 50 MB or 25 MB**.

How can I achieve this in `Javascript - JQuery or PHP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP you can limit the file download size with this header function:

```
header('Content-Length: {No.of MB} x 1024 bytes');
```